# How to Loop and move directories to another using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am having the following code.
My requirement is that for every item in $B I have to move the same items in $A to another location

```
PS H:\> $A = "'20201015-AAA','20201026-BBB','20201104-CCC','20201106-DDD','20201108-EEE','20201120-FFF'"

PS H:\> $B = "20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF"

PS H:\> $A | foreach-object{
        foreach ($B in $B){
        if ($B -match $_.Fullname) 
            {
             Write-Host "Moving the duplicates..."
             $_ = $_ -replace "'",""
             
             Write-Host "Value = $_"
             Move-Item -Path "C:\testsession\$_" -Destination "C:\testsession2"
             
             Write-Host Path is "C:\testsession\$_"
             Write-Host "Packages moved.."
             }
             }
        Write-Host "$B $_"
        }
```

Result

```
Moving the duplicates...
Value = 20201015-AAA,20201026-BBB,20201104-CCC,20201106-DDD,20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF
C:\testsession\20201015-AAA,20201026-BBB,20201104-CCC,20201106-DDD,20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF
Packages moved..
20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF 20201015-AAA,20201026-BBB,20201104-CCC,20201106-DDD,20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF
```

Could anyone help me format this loop so that each of the file in $B is matched with $A. Then from $A it is moved to destination as stated above

Thanks

Comment: `Foreach $B in $B` Change the first object variable and does that help at all?

Comment: `$B = "20201108-EEE,20201120-FFF"` makes $B a single string, not an array.. $A is an array of strings, not an array of `FileInfo` objects, so there is no `FullName` property to match. Read about `Get-ChildItem` and/or `Get-Item`

Comment: $A = "'20201015-AAA','20201026-BBB','20201104-CCC','20201106-DDD','20201108-EEE','20201120-FFF'" needs to be $A = @('20201015-AAA','20201026-BBB','20201104-CCC','20201106-DDD','20201108-EEE','20201120-FFF') Same goes for B

Answer (score 0):

Tried this and its working.

```
PS H:\> $A = @('20201015-AAA','20201026-BBB','20201104-CCC','20201106-DDD','20201108-EEE','20201120-FFF')
PS H:\> $B = @('20201108-EEE','20201120-FFF')

PS H:\> $A | foreach-object{
        foreach ($X in $B){
        if ($X -match $_) 
            {
             Write-Host "Moving the duplicates..."
             $_ = $_ -replace "'",""
             
             Write-Host "Value = $_"
             Write-Host Path is "C:\testsession\$_"
             Write-Host "Packages moved.."
             }
             }
        Write-Host "$B $_"
        }
        
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201015-AAA
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201026-BBB
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201104-CCC
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201106-DDD
Moving the duplicates...
Value = 20201108-EEE
Path is C:\testsession\20201108-EEE
Packages moved..
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201108-EEE
Moving the duplicates...
Value = 20201120-FFF
Path is C:\testsession\20201120-FFF
Packages moved..
20201108-EEE 20201120-FFF 20201120-FFF
```